# iterate around values in a bulk collected table - extractvalue

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have a piece of PL/SQL which does:

```
   SELECT *
     BULK COLLECT INTO table_1
     FROM XMLTABLE (
             '//Match'
             PASSING l_xml_string
             COLUMNS col_1 VARCHAR2 (8) PATH '@col_1' ,
                     col_2 VARCHAR2 (40) PATH '@col_2');
```

I then store these as an XML variable using XMLAGG.

I want to join the col_1 value of a view, but the problem is when I use the EXTRACTVALUE function (from the aggregated xml) I get a terrible explain plan (full table scans over using an index) over when I pass it a single value - even when there's one 1 record within the xml.

When I do the extract before entering this table (storing it in a variable and then joining against the variable) it takes the correct path, but to do so I limit myself to 1 result (where rownum < 2) when I need to remove this restriction.

When I do:

```
select col_1 
into l_col_1 from
TABLE (table_1);
```

it displays:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Is there another way to do this or:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (data.COLUMN_VALUE ....
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the values that you've extracted from your xml via the first query? Will you be using them to insert into a table? Update something? Return a value to the calling procedure?

Comment: Return a value. I aim to join on table_1.col_1 (value(s).

Comment: Why can't you just use the initial select as part of the join directly? That way, you don't have to faff around with storing stuff only to return it so that it can be passed into another query.

Comment: If I do (select ......... from table (table_1), other_view where col_1 = view_col then I get a bad execution plan also. It would be acceptable that in the cases where it returned more than 1 it ran bad (this would be <5% of all queries) - however it impacts all runs.

Comment: Why join on table_1? Why not just join directly on the xmltable? `select .... from other_view vw inner join (select col_1, col_2 from xmltable(...)) x on (vw.view_col = x.col_1)`?